# 'Activate Contract' Button (JavaScript execute) returns error

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I made a detail button with the intention of clicking it to change the Contract Status to 'Activated'.

I used the guided steps below, where it says 'Select Field Type' and then 'Select Field' (I chose the Contract object and the status picklist field), and clicked 'Select Operator' and chose ' = ' and then set it equal to 'Activated'. I checked for Syntax errors with the button and it said it was fine.

I get the following error when using the Button:

"A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:

expected expression, got '='"

Here is the exact line in the button definition.

```
{!Contract2__c.Contract_Status__c} = 'Activated'
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Use like this way to assign `Activated` value to `Contract_Status__c`, in onclick javascript button code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 
var contractObj = new sforce.SObject("Contract2__c");
contractObj.Contract_Status__c = 'Activated';
sforce.connection.update([contractObj]); 
location.reload();
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59941/discussion-between-santanu-boral-and-natalie-spatharakis).

Comment: is that working for you?